# Running a Java Program

Tags: java

I looked at some other SO questions, didn't find anything that solved my problem... I have a Main.java file (below) and a OthelloLib.jar file without associated source files.

Running `javac Main.java` fails with

```
Main.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SimplePlayer
location: class Main
        OthelloPlayer p1 = new SimplePlayer();
```

and a few more errors. SimplePlayer and BetterPlayer are defined in the jar. How do I tell java about this jar? This command: `javac -classpath .:OthelloLib.jar -g Main.java` doesn't cause an error, but I still don't know how to run the program. If I run `java -classpath .:OthelloLib.jar Main`, java complains:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TimeoutException`

but TimeoutException.java is in the same directory as Main.java.

I don't know where to look up basic Java stuff like this, so here I am!

```
public class Main {
  public Main() { }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OthelloPlayer p1 = new SimplePlayer();
    OthelloPlayer p2 = new BetterPlayer();
    OthelloObserver o = new OthelloSimObserver();

    // Create an untimed game
    OthelloGame g = new OthelloGame(p1, p2, o);
    System.out.println("Starting game");
    g.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: `public Main() { }` isn't necessary.  Not every class needs a constructor, and since it does nothing, it's just cluttering your code.

Comment: legacy code from a class a couple years ago. i'm glad java doesn't require that.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run

```
javac -classpath .:OthelloLib.jar Main.java
```

to compile, then

```
java -classpath .:OthelloLib.jar Main
```

In each case the `-classpath .:OthelloLib.jar` option tells Java where to find `SimplePlayer` and other classes you need; it doesn't know to look in the JAR file on its own. And you do need to tell both the compiler and the virtual machine where to look for the classes.

*EDIT*: Looks like you added something about `TimeoutException` since I wrote this... did you remember to compile `TimeoutException.java`? And is the `TimeoutException.class` file in the same directory as `Main.class`?

Comment: i tried that second command... java complains about a different problem... seems like it found the classes buried in the jar, though.

Comment: Ah... yeah, at this stage I'd suggest doing things using a text editor and the command line. Once you understand the process, then head back to Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Note: You can do all this within a good IDE like eclipse or netbeans by adding the library to your project. The rest gets handled automagically.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set a reference to OthelloLib.jar or invoking the javacompiler with the library as a parameter?

```
java -classpath .:OthelloLib.jar -g Main
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you import all the libraries?

like

```
import a.b.c. OthelloPlayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the classpath when you call your program?

Something like the following might work:

```
java -cp .:OthelloLib.jar Main
```